# How to trigger IRC server to get the server response as either code 641 or 352

Tags: irc

I am aware that the response from the IRC server when the codes are 641 and 352 will be as follows:

```
352 <channel> <user> <host> <server> <nick> <H|G>[*][@|+] :<hopcount> <real name>

641 yournick #channel lat long
```

But I am not sure when we will receive such responses from the server.

Do we need to trigger the server to get such responses.

I am totally clueless. Could you please help me in this regard.

Basically, I need to get the server response with code 641/352 so that I can capture location details of channel/user and display the same on the map.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a list of common raw replies: http://mirc.net/raws/
`641` is unknown to me and the website given, that means it's a custom raw event from that specific irc server version. You should ask the network administrators.
`352` is a reply to the `/who` command. A "tutorial" about the who command and it replies can be found at http://members.multimania.nl/wiebe2000/who.html